# How to "replicate" this effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to replicate the effect in this image.

[image]

Which sort of brush can i use to draw simmetric lines in a layer mask , or an upper layer (to apply to layer below) ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any symmetrical lines, and the design is not symmetrical at all. Also it doesn't look like these were made with a brush. The lines look a bit like a bar chart which has been placed over a photo montage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch it more careful. You should see that it's not mere masking with histogram like shape. The same shape is used also as image material in some slices. The woman is also sliced and used twice - I see a third eye.

Make the histogram style shape in Illustrator. Copy and paste it to Photoshop. You can use it to make selections with magic wand or paste it into layer mask as you planned.

Illustrator is not a must altough it's a little faster. As well you can make adjacent rectangular selections in Photoshop and fill them.

Answer (score 0):

The image looks like it is a few brochures that are stacked on top of each other. The lines in the image seem to actually be going at a diagonal. Just wanted to clarify that since I didn't know if it was the entire photo you want to recreate or just the effect on one of the brochures. I will err on the side of the effect on one of the brochures.

To directly answer your question, there are many different ways to create these elements. Here is one way:

In photoshop, create the rectangular shapes over the image of the woman. This can be done with the pen tool or using the rectangle tool. Color the lines the color you want them and if this is the effect that's desired, then great.

The lines in the example, however, have a texture on them. In that case, import the texture you would like to use for the lines and place it over the woman. Select all of the lines (you can hold shift to select multiple shapes in photoshop), right click and create a smart object. Now hold command (ctrl on windows) and select the thumbnail of the layer of the new smart object. This will create "marching ants" over all of the lines (thus creating a selection based on the lines). Now select your background and click "add layer mask" at the bottom of the layers panel and your background will now be in the shape of the lines you created.

If I could provide some feedback on your question to help you not get downvotes in the future, please provide a little more detail about what "effect" exactly you are trying to achieve. The photo isn't actually an effect, but the black and white style, the multiple brochures in the image and the design on the brochure itself all could be, so we must guess as to what you're actually wanting.